# Standardized charity documentation in Israel?

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, tzedakah-charity, state-of-israel

Most American charities, to preserve their tax-exempt status, have to file a [Form 990](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IRS_tax_forms#990) annually with the federal government, detailing some important statistics about their organization, including how much of the money they collect goes to overhead, advertising, and other expenses not directly related to their stated mission. Websites like [Charity Navigator](http://www.charitynavigator.org) make these forms available online and also analyze and categorize charities based on the numbers in these forms.

Is there an equivalent mechanism in Israel (or in other countries, for that matter)?

Related question: If an Israeli charity has an "American friends of" offshoot in the US, the statistics for that offshoot in Form 990 only reflect the auxiliary fund-raising activities of the American offshoot, not the full activities of the parent organization, right?

Answer (score 1):

There is, "-ish".
There are different forms of registered charities in Israel, see e.g. [MALKAR / מלכ"ר](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%93_%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%95%D7%97), and [Amuta / עמותה](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%94) (linked to Hebrew wikipedia for lack of a better source... )

I'm not an accountant, but as I understand it they each have different forms to fill out... You can check the [Justice Ministry's site](http://www.justice.gov.il/MOJHeb/RasutHataagidim/RashamAmutot/TfasimNew/) (but you have to sign up to get the forms...)

Answer (score 0):

Have not been able to find one for Israel, however here is one for the UK

http://www.charity-commission.gov.uk/

here is one for Australia

http://www.auscharity.org/